# Parsing fields of JSON file in Java

Tags: java, json, database

I have a JSON file of the following format and would like to parse the data to insert into a table. I'm stuck on how to extract data from the file. The data looks like this:

```
{"business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA", "full_address": "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018", "hours": {"Tuesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Monday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"], "city": "Phoenix", "review_count": 7, "name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "neighborhoods": [], "longitude": -111.98375799999999, "state": "AZ", "stars": 3.5, "latitude": 33.499313000000001, "attributes": {"By Appointment Only": true}, "type": "business"}
```

I have this code until now:

```
fReader = new FileReader(filePath);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String line;
bufferedReader.readLine();
int index = 0;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     String businessInfo[] = line.split("\t");
                
     //add a new object based on my OOP design
```

Comment: There are several libraries for this issue. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: What about splitting by '\t' as I have shown above?

Comment: Describe _stuck_.

Comment: As `'\t'` escape character stands for *tab* and I do not see any *tabs* in your JSON, it won't work. There is no escape character for *space*, but you can use use an empty string `' '` to separate parts of the JSON file.

Comment: You can read the file and convert it into string. Then you can use Jackson ObjectMapper to conver string to JsonNode which you can play with. It is very rich in features. `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Why don;t you use a JSON parser like Gson or Jackson etc? Pass the payload to it and it will return you back the Object which you will cast to your type.